# Edit listbox (or other control) of remote application in c#?

Tags: listbox

I'd like to know how to edit a listbox of a remote application in C#.
For example: add (or delete) an entry in the taskmanager's list.

Is this possible? How can I do this in the most stable manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to create you own Control in C# ?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2016/Writing-your-Custom-Control-step-by-step

this might help you.

Comment: No, i mean edit a listbox (and maybe other controls?) from another process, like taskmgr.exe. Thanks for your reply tho :)